# Cambiar el texto de un enlace, la etiqueta <a> con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Quiero cambiar el texto de la etiqueta a con JavaScript, obtengo dos valores de un formulario y quiero pasarlo a la barra de navegación, pero no puedo.

```
<body>      
    <<div class="topnav">
        <a>Inicio</a>           
    </div>


    <div id="container">
        <h1>&bull; Datos de Sesion &bull;</h1>
        <div class="underline"></div>

        <form action="#" method="post" id="loguin_form" onsubmit="myFunction()">
            <div class="nombre">
              <label for="nombre"></label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" id="nombre_input" required>
            </div>
            <div class="apellido">
              <label for="apellido"></label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido" name="apellido" id="apellido_input" required>
            </div>

            <div class="submit">
              <input type="submit" value="Ingresar" id="form_button" />
            </div>
        </form><!-- // End form -->
    </div><!-- // End #container -->
</body>
```

este es el JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
var nom, ape;
nom = document.forms["loguin_form"]['nombre'].value;
ape = document.forms["loguin_form"]['apellido'].value;
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML = "Usuario: " + nom + " " + ape;
}
```

y no hay ningún cambio, como si no hubiese hecho el código. si coloco un alert con los datos que obtengo del formulario ellos aparecen.

Comment: La parte de cambiar el texto del _anchor_ luce bien, pero no incluyes tu formulario `loguin_form`, que es donde parece estar el error.

Comment: el formulario esta debajo del la etiqueta <a>, mejor dicho, es independiente del formulario.

Comment: no pongas la etiqueta de C++, pues claramente no estas usando dicho lenguaje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En general el código de tu función luce bien. Hay un par de cambios que realizar, Si no debe haber envío real del formulario y lo que quieres es ejecutar la función:

- La función debe retornar `false`
- El OnSubmit debe retornar el valor de la función.
- Referencia a los elementos `<input>` por su id, no por su nombre.

Esos cambios, darían como resultado algo como:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var nom, ape;
  nom = document.forms["login_form"]['nombre_input'].value;
  ape = document.forms["login_form"]['apellido_input'].value;
  document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML = "Usuario: " + nom + " " + ape;
  console.log(nom + " " + ape);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="topnav">
     <a id="envio">Inicio</a>            
   </div>
   <form id="login_form" OnSubmit="return myFunction();">
     <label for"nombre" />
     <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" id="nombre_input" required /><br />
     <label for"apellido" />
     <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido" name="apelido" id="apellido_input" required /><br />
     <button type="submit">Actualizar</button>
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: hola, gracias por responder. te cuento que funciona por milisegundos lo que me propones, en detalle, se realiza el cambio pero de inmediato se vuelve a su valor anterior, que es "Inicio". Sabes porque?

Comment: Ahora que veo cómo está tu formulario, actualicé mi respuesta. La había escrito antes de tu edición. Un saludo.

Comment: hola, gracias por responder. te cuento que funciona por milisegundos lo que me propones, en detalle, se realiza el cambio pero de inmediato se vuelve a su valor anterior, que es "Inicio". Sabes porque?

Comment: ¿Eso te pasa al darle clic al botón ejecutar en mi respuesta?

Comment: Pregunto porque a mi me funciona bien, en Chrome, ¿qué navegador utilizas?

Comment: No, aca en la página. y utilizo el mismo navegador

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94530/discussion-between-jachguate-and-leonard-jusa-ockonell).